# run tox on different python patch versions

Tags: python, testing, tox-globinterpreter

In short: Is there a way to have `tox` cycle on patch versions of python?

Long: I want the tests to be run on 2.7.7, 2.7.8, and so on, basically I'm staging on 2.7.6 and want to see if I can get rid of this warning

https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning

before going into production.

(Of course I've already tested it "by hand" with pyenv, setting 2.7.x as global building a virtualenv and testing into it, but it would be nice to have continuous integration run every time all the possible combinations)

Comment: I created an feature request for it: https://github.com/tox-dev/tox/issues/1591

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test a library against different Python \*patch\* versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57245532/how-to-test-a-library-against-different-python-patch-versions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which exact version `tox` uses when specifying `-e py27` depends on your platform, default paths, and your PATH. If you want to have full control over which version it takes, you should install `tox-globinterpreter` and run

```
for x in $(seq 7 12); do
    tox --scan /opt/python/2.7."$x"/bin/python
    tox -r -e py27
done
```

in the directory where your `tox.ini` is installed. The above assumes you have your python installation next to each other under `/opt/python/` with the version number as install directory under that, other locations/schemes are of course possible, but only when there is some regularity you can use a `for` loop.

`tox-globinterpreter` still only allows you one binary python version per `tox` version indicator (`py27`, `py35`, `py36`, `pypy`, etc) but allows you fine tuned control over selecting the actual python used for each of these.