# How to test a library against different Python *patch* versions?

Tags: python, testing, tox

I'm writing a library and want to test against different Python patch versions, like 3.7.1, 3.7.2, etc

I've been using `tox` for a long time, however, according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40962573/2142577), it doesn't really support this kind of usage.

Any suggestions?

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary? According to the Python FAQ ``it’s guaranteed that interfaces will remain the same throughout a series of bugfix releases``. And the Python executable is only indicated by a major and minor version. So installing e.q. 3.7.1 and 3.7.2 and have them both work is probably not trivial.

Comment: @RolandSmith That's true for 99% cases, but for my usage it's not. For example, in Python 3.6.7 they fixed bpo-6700, which changed the behavior of `inspect.getsource` completely, and I'm using this function. There could be more of such potential behavior changes that I'm not even aware of, that's why this kind of testing is needed.

Comment: In case of a bugfix like bpo-6700, I'd probably code my library to the corrected version. And inspect `sys.version_info` and simply raise an exception if the version of Python is affected by this bug. As in `you need at least Python 3.6.x or 3.7.y for this library to work correctly`.

Comment: @RolandSmith I've already done that by enforcing Python version in pyproject.toml. However the thing is, my code can change, it can bring in or remove buggy APIs, so the version requirement can also change accordingly.

Comment: If you have installed different Python minors, define new envs with custom `basepython`: `envlist = py37{2,3,4}`, specialize via `[testenv:py372] basepython=path/to/python372` etc.

Comment: @hoefling Interesting. Let me try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a one of check against 3.8.1 (assuming your python3.8 points to 3.8.2) you can use the [discover flag](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#cmdoption-tox-discover)

```sh
tox --discover /path/to/python3.8.1 -e py38
```

If you want to define an environment that always uses 3.8.1 you can do that by defining a new tox environment and setting [basepython](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#conf-basepython) as `python3.8.1`.

```
[testenv:py381]
basepython = python3.8.1

[testenv:py382]
basepython = python3.8.2
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you give an example of `tox.ini`, where I have both Python 3.8.1 and 3.8.2 as environments?

Comment: Looks nice. Let's me try it.

Comment: I got it to work. I have to use `testenv:python383` instead of `testenv:py383`, otherwise tox will complain about `InterpreterNotFound`. The solution comes from https://github.com/tox-dev/tox/issues/378#issuecomment-413937359, so I'm guessing the root cause is the same, but I didn't investigate.

Anyway, upvoted and accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

Probably the least troublesome (but tedious) way is to install different versions of Python sequentially in a jail or VM and then test your code on it.

If you install Python from source on a UNIX-like system, you could try installing them side by side using different prefixes (eg `/opt/patch1`, `opt/patch2` etc.)
And then *expliticly* run your test with the correct python like `/opt/patch1/bin/python3`. One caveat; I'm not sure if the Python executable would find the correct shared library in this case.

The ms-windows installer lets you pick an install location. If you instruct it *not* to put Python in the PATH and not set up file associations and the like, that might also work. You would also have to explicitly invoke the correct Python with the full path.

Answer (score 1):

I would go Docker and run it container.

```
$ docker run -it --rm -w /opt -v "$PWD:/opt" python:3.4.2 python <script.py>
```

> ```
> -it   - interactive mode  
> --rm  - remove container after the run
> -w    - working directory inside container
> -v    - map directory $PWD from host to /opt inside container
> <container>   - python:3.4.2
> <command>     - python script.py
> ```

You can see what images are available with the command:

```
$ curl -s https://registry.hub.docker.com/v1/repositories/python/tags | \
    jq -r .[].name | grep "^[23][.0-9]*$" | sort -V
2
2.7
2.7.7
2.7.8
2.7.9
2.7.10
2.7.11
2.7.12
2.7.13
2.7.14
2.7.15
2.7.16
3
3.2
3.2.6
3.3
3.3.5
3.3.6
3.3.7
3.4
3.4.1
3.4.2
3.4.3
3.4.4
3.4.5
3.4.6
3.4.7
3.4.8
3.4.9
3.4.10
3.5
3.5.0
3.5.1
3.5.2
3.5.3
3.5.4
3.5.5
3.5.6
3.5.7
3.6
3.6.0
3.6.1
3.6.2
3.6.3
3.6.4
3.6.5
3.6.6
3.6.7
3.6.8
3.6.9
3.7
3.7.0
3.7.1
3.7.2
3.7.3
3.7.4
```

`grep` filters out beta and alpha versions, so if you need them - just remove the grep.

If you need Python version that is not present in the list, you can build `docker` image with custom Python.

take eg Alpine linux (it's really small)
https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/f82205cde8f0a5ffa276103a50d843edced67757/3.7/alpine3.10/Dockerfile